# How to replace already-printed text in the command prompt?

Tags: c, text, command-prompt

A lot of times I've seen text-based programs which replace text which has already been printed. For instance, imagine a program where the progress is printed as

```
Loading: 5%
```

and then it says

```
Loading: 10%
```

and so on, *without* printing new text which is *appended*?

How is this done? I haven't seen any such functions available in the library (in this case C). I have an idea, though: There is a character you can write which returns the prompt to the beginning of current line (`\r` I believe). Could this be used to "overwrite" what you've already printed to the command prompt?

Comment: Using `printf` `\r` is the way to go. A bit more complicated is the use of the curses library.

Comment: @George Kastrinis: Nope, not yet, but I will now. ^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most consoles, writing a bare carriage return `\r` without a newline after it will return the cursor to the beginning of the current line, allowing you to overwrite the existing text.  Writing the backspace character `\b` also moves the cursor back one character.

For simple behavior, such as a progress indicator, this is all you need.  For more complex behavior, you need to control the terminal through non-standard means.  On Unix-based systems, the [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/) library can be used—it gives you full control over the cursor location, text color, keyboard echoing, more fine-grained keyboard input, and more.

On Windows, there's a [suite of functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682010%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for manipulating consoles, and they can do mostly the same things as Unix consoles.

Comment: Thanks! And here is an example: `echo -n "HELLO WORLD\r"; sleep 2; echo "HELLO EARTH"`, where `-n` is used to prevent new lines from `echo`. This outputs `HELLO WORLD` which is replaced with `HELLO EARTH` after 2 seconds. Removing `/r` would make it `HELLO WORLDHELLO EARTH` instead. So as mentioned, `/r` returns cursor to beginning of line.

Answer (score 2):

One way that I have seen is to just print the backspace character a number of times and then replace whatever you erased with the new text.

The backspace character is an ASCII control character represented by \b.